# Adding files to an existing jar file in java

Tags: java

I need some help with using the following code to modify and existing jar file:

```
    String command = "cmd /c jar uf " + dirToModify + " " + Main.getMain().outputLocate.getSelectedFile();
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    dirToModify = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\myfile.jar"
    Main.getMain().outputLocate.getSelectedFile() = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\myfolder"
```

Basically I want to add the files/folders from `myfolder` to `myfile.jar` but with the above code it will add a shortcut to my `C:` drive not the files from `myfolder`.

Also I did look at other posts but none help me with this problem.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify a path relative to the JAR root. See -c switch maybe? Or move to `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\ ` before executing the command?

Comment: Why do you need to do this at runtime?

Comment: `"C:\\Users\\Me\Desktop\\myfolder.jar"`, as `"\\"` is the notation for backslash.

Comment: ok so I see you updated your question, does it still add only the "C:" to your jar even when you have "\\" in your paths or is the problem somewhere else now? Did you try running that "jar uf..." command from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest, first checking, if adding one file, at a time, is working with this code. This will make clear if problem is in 'folder addition' or 'file addition'. 
If file addition doesn't work, your basic jar update logic is broken. So you can ask for solution to that problem.
If file addition works, try recursively adding all files from destination folder.

Comment: I already attempted it manually and got the same problem where it will add my 'C:' to the jar file.

Comment: Hint: you'd need to keep the jar-file and input-file under same folder. and then excecute "jar uf jar-file input-file(s)"